# cannot get return variable(s) in javascript when using require in solidity

Tags: solidity, javascript, react, bytes32, require

I have a function in solidity that returns a few bytes32 variables.  I cannot for the life of me access those variables.  Can someone please help?

```
function getData() public returns (bytes32, bytes32, bytes32, bytes32) {
    require(approvedAccessors[msg.sender] == true);

    return (a, b, c, d);
}
```

then in my js file I tried:

```
static async getInitialProps(props) {
  const { address } = props.query;
  const myData = MyData(address);
  const tempData = await myData.methods.getPrivateData().call();

  return { address };
}
```

and this:

```
static async getInitialProps(props) {
  const { address } = props.query;
  const myData = MyData(address);
  await myData.methods.getData().call().then(function(v) {
    var res1 = web3.utils.hexToAscii(v[0].toString());

  })
  return { address };
}
```

I keep getting:

```
Couldn't decode bytes32 from ABI: 0x The size doesn't match.
Error: Couldn't decode bytes32 from ABI: 0x The size doesn't match.
    at SolidityTypeBytes.formatOutputBytes [as _outputFormatter]
```

After 2 days of debugging, I finally found the problem.  The problem is using require.

```
require(approvedAccessors[msg.sender] == true);
```

Without this line, the code works perfectly.  including this line will cause the above error.  I wonder if this is a bug.  I have checked that the condition is met.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer, but since I don't have enough reputation to comment, and you look desperate, here it goes: your function in solidity is called getData(), but in your js file you are calling getPrivateData().